# send document and subdocument data in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to send data from document and subdocument in json format,in return of request which contains userID and may or may not contain limit(number of sub docs to show) , to(date) and from(date)

my schema

```
const logInfoSchema = new Schema(
  {
    description: { type: String, required: true, default: "" },
    duration: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
    date: { type: String }
  },
  { versionKey: false }
);

const userInfoSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    log: [logInfoSchema]
  },
  { versionKey: false }
);
```

current code, sends data with all log

```
app.get("/api/exercise/log", (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.query.userId;
  console.log(userId);
  if (!userId) {
    res.send("enter user id");
  } else {
    userInfo.findById(userId, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return err;
      } else {
        res.json(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the request url?

Comment: `/api/exercise/log?userId=5f1a48d64c7a1230d91d129c` but can be like `/api/exercise/log?userId=333&from=2019-3-13&to=2020-3-13&limit=5` @prax

Comment: by log I mean all the elements in log array(see schema) `{"count":11,"_id":"5f1a48d64c7a1230d91d129c","username":"xrahulx","log":[{"description":"fff","duration":3,"_id":"5f1a48df4c7a1230d91d129d","date":"Fri May 10 2019"},{"description":"hhh","duration":3,"_id":"5f1a4a5bdfd648354d80d804","date":"Fri Jul 24 2020"},{"description":"hh","duration":3,"_id":"5f1a4ad52547f937215c529a","date":"Fri Jul 24 2020"},{"description":"log","duration":3,"_id":"5f1a4b4f7163d9383ef52f85","date":"Fri Jul 24 2020"},{"description":"log","duration":3,"_id":"5f1a4b73b9cc9038873b129f","date":"Fri Jul 24 2020"}]}`

Comment: but I also need to limit number of elements returned from log , using limit variable(if present) and its not necessary for to and from to be present

Comment: Does this help you: `db.test.find({_id:userId, "log.date": { "$gt": from, "$lt": to}},callback) `

Comment: to and from may or maynot be present

Comment: Use if and else ,create two queries one when they are present and one when not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let logProcessing = (log, to, from, limit) => {
  if (limit < 0) {
    limit = 0;
  }

  if (dateValidator(to) && dateValidator(from)) {
    return log
      .filter(
        date => new Date(date["date"]) >= from && new Date(date["date"]) <= to
      )
      .slice(0, limit);
  } else if (dateValidator(from)) {
    return log.filter(date => new Date(date["date"]) >= from).slice(0, limit);
  } else if (dateValidator(to)) {
    return log.filter(date => new Date(date["date"]) <= to).slice(0, limit);
  } else {
    return log.slice(0, limit);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use query operators to find logs beetween given dates and use the `limit`
to limit the no. of results.

```
app.get("/api/exercise/log", (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.query.userId;
    const from = req.query.from;
    const to = req.query.to;
    console.log(userId);
    if (userId && from && to){

        userInfo.find({_id:userId, "log.date": { "$gt": from, "$lt":to}},
                            {sort: {'date': -1}, limit: 20},(er,data) => {
                                if (err) {
                                   return err;
                                }  
                                else {
                                   res.json(data);
                                 }
                           });
    }
    else{
        if (!userId) {
          res.send("enter user id");
        } else {
          userInfo.findById(userId, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              return err;
            } else {
              res.json(data);
            }
          });
        }
      }

  });
```